# java.io.IOException: bt socket closed, read return: -1

Tags: java, android, eclipse, obd-ii

As i am working on OBD Reader Demo .Through my app i am  trying to connect obd reader device and my app is installed in Nexus 7.OBD Reader device is connecting to other apps which is available on google play but if i am connecting with my app it is getting error java.io.IOException: bt socket closed, read return: -1 after connection establish .Any suggestions...
    =========================================================

```
 **MainActivity:-**  

        import java.io.BufferedReader;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.InputStream;
        import java.io.InputStreamReader;
        import java.io.OutputStream;
        import java.lang.reflect.Method;
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.Set;
        import java.util.UUID;

        import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
        import android.app.AlertDialog;
        import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
        import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
        import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
        import android.content.DialogInterface;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.ListView;
        import android.widget.TextView;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        import com.virgosys.demo.commands.SpeedObdCommand;
        import com.virgosys.demo.commands.engine.EngineRPMObdCommand;
        import com.virgosys.demo.commands.fuel.FindFuelTypeObdCommand;

        public class MainActivity extends Bluetooth {

            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            private Button On, Off, Visible, list;
            private BluetoothAdapter BA;
            private Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices;
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            private ListView lv;
            private BluetoothDevice device;
            // private UUID uuid;

            // private BluetoothSocketWrapper bluetoothSocket;

            private BluetoothSocket socket;
            private String deviceAddress;
            String RPM, Speed, FuelType;
            private TextView uuidTextView, deviceTextView, showRpm, showSpeed,
                    showFuelType, tv_connection_e, tv_connection_f;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                showRpm = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.show_rpm));
                showSpeed = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_speed));
                showFuelType = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_fueltype));
                uuidTextView = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_uuid));
                deviceTextView = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_device));
                // tv_connection_e = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_device));
                // tv_connection_f = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.show_error));
                On = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
                Off = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
                Visible = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
                list = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

                lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

                BA = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

                try {
                    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

                    StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = "";
                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        log.append(line);
                    }
                    TextView tv_connection_e = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.show_error);
                    tv_connection_e.setText(log.toString());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }

            public void on(View view) {
                if (!BA.isEnabled()) {
                    Intent turnOn = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                    startActivityForResult(turnOn, 0);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Turned on",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already on",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            public void list(View view) {
                ArrayList deviceStrs = new ArrayList();
                final ArrayList devices = new ArrayList();

                BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

                pairedDevices = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();
                if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
                    for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                        deviceStrs.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                        devices.add(device.getAddress());

                    }
                }
                // show list
                final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

                ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                        android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice,
                        deviceStrs.toArray(new String[deviceStrs.size()]));

                alertDialog.setSingleChoiceItems(adapter, -1,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                                int position = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView()
                                        .getCheckedItemPosition();
                                deviceAddress = (String) devices.get(position);

                                System.out.println("Device Address-->" + deviceAddress);

                                /*
                                 * Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                                 * SecondActivity.class); i.putExtra("uuid",
                                 * "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
                                 * i.putExtra("deviceAddress", deviceAddress);
                                 * i.putExtra("RPM", RPM); i.putExtra("Speed", Speed);
                                 * startActivity(i);
                                 */
                                try {
                                    dothings();
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                                // save deviceAddress
                            }

                        });

                alertDialog.setTitle("Choose Bluetooth device");
                alertDialog.show();

            }

            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            protected void dothings() throws InterruptedException {

                System.out.println("Inside  Do things");
                System.out.println("Device address in Do things -->" + deviceAddress);
                device = BA.getRemoteDevice(deviceAddress);
                // UUID SERIAL_UUID = device.getUuids()[0].getUuid();
                // uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
                System.out.println("Device Name-->" + device.getName());
                System.out.println("Device Address-->" + device.getAddress());
                System.out.println("Device Bond State-->" + device.getBondState());
                System.out.println("Device Type-->" + device.getType());
                System.out.println("Device UUIDS-->" + device.getUuids());

                ConnectThread t = new ConnectThread(device);
                t.start();

                showRpm.setText(RPM);
                showSpeed.setText(Speed);
                showFuelType.setText(FuelType);
                uuidTextView.setText("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
                deviceTextView.setText(deviceAddress);

            }

            public void off(View view) {
                BA.disable();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Turned off", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }

            public void visible(View view) {
                Intent getVisible = new Intent(
                        BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
                startActivityForResult(getVisible, 0);

            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

                return true;

            }

            private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
                private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;

                private final UUID WELL_KNOWN_UUID = UUID
                        .fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

                private Object e;

                public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
                    // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket,because
                    // mmSocket is final
                    BluetoothSocket tmp = null;

                    // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
                    try {
                        tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(WELL_KNOWN_UUID);
                        // This is the trick
                        Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket",
                                new Class[] { int.class });
                        tmp = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    mmSocket = tmp;
                }

                public void run() {

                    System.out.println("Trying to connect...");
                    // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
                    BA.cancelDiscovery();

                    try {
                        // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
                        // until it succeeds or throws an exception
                        mmSocket.connect();
                        System.out.println("Connection established");
                        // tv_connection_e.setText(e.print.stacktrace);
                        ConnectedThread tc = new ConnectedThread(mmSocket);
                        tc.start();

                    } catch (IOException connectException) {
                        // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
                        System.out.println("Fail to connect!");

                        try {
                            mmSocket.close();
                        } catch (IOException closeException) {
                            System.out.println("Fail to close connection");

                        }
                        return;
                    }
                }

                /** Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
                public void cancel() {
                    try {
                        mmSocket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    }
                }
            }

            private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
                private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
                private final InputStream mmInStream;
                private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

                public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
                    mmSocket = socket;
                    InputStream tmpIn = null;
                    OutputStream tmpOut = null;
                    try {
                        tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                        tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    }
                    System.out.println("Inside the thread");
                    mmInStream = tmpIn;
                    mmOutStream = tmpOut;
                    try {
                        EngineRPMObdCommand engineRpmCommand = new EngineRPMObdCommand();
                        SpeedObdCommand speedCommand = new SpeedObdCommand();
                        FindFuelTypeObdCommand fueltypeCommand = new FindFuelTypeObdCommand();
                        System.out.println("Inside the try block");

                        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                            System.out.println("Inside while");

                            // TODO handle commands result
                            Log.d("Poonam",
                                    "RPM: " + engineRpmCommand.getFormattedResult());
                            Log.d("Poonam",
                                    "Speed: " + speedCommand.getFormattedResult());
                            Log.d("Poonam",
                                    "FuelType: " + fueltypeCommand.getFormattedResult());

                            RPM = engineRpmCommand.getFormattedResult();
                            Speed = speedCommand.getFormattedResult();
                            FuelType = fueltypeCommand.getFormattedResult();

                            try {
                                engineRpmCommand.run(mmInStream, mmOutStream);
                                speedCommand.run(mmInStream, mmOutStream);
                                fueltypeCommand.run(mmInStream, mmOutStream);
                                System.out.println("Commands Processed");
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            System.out.println("outside try catch");
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        System.out.println("inside catch before while");
                    }
                    // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
                    // member streams are final

                }

                public void run() {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; // buffer store for the stream
                    int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

                    // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
                    while (true) {
                    }

                }

                /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
                public void write(byte[] bytes) {
                    try {
                        mmOutStream.write(bytes);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    }
                }

                /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
                public void cancel() {
                    try {
                        mmSocket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }






    **Bluetooth.java**

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
    import java.lang.reflect.Method;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.UUID;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
    import android.util.Log;

    public class Bluetooth extends Activity{

        private BluetoothSocketWrapper bluetoothSocket;
        private BluetoothDevice device;
        private boolean secure;
        private BluetoothAdapter adapter;
        private List<UUID> uuidCandidates;
        private int candidate;


        /**
         * @param device the device
         * @param secure if connection should be done via a secure socket
         * @param adapter the Android BT adapter
         * @param uuidCandidates a list of UUIDs. if null or empty, the Serial PP id is used
         * @return 
         */
        public void BluetoothConnector(BluetoothDevice device, boolean secure, BluetoothAdapter adapter,
                List<UUID> uuidCandidates) {
            this.device = device;
            this.secure = secure;
            this.adapter = adapter;
            this.uuidCandidates = uuidCandidates;

            if (this.uuidCandidates == null || this.uuidCandidates.isEmpty()) {
                this.uuidCandidates = new ArrayList<UUID>();
                this.uuidCandidates.add(UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
            }
        }

        public BluetoothSocketWrapper connect() throws IOException {
            boolean success = false;
            while (selectSocket()) {
                adapter.cancelDiscovery();

                try {
                    bluetoothSocket.connect();
                    success = true;
                    break;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //try the fallback
                    try {
                        bluetoothSocket = new FallbackBluetoothSocket(bluetoothSocket.getUnderlyingSocket());
                        Thread.sleep(500);                  
                        bluetoothSocket.connect();
                        success = true;
                        break;  
                    } catch (FallbackException e1) {
                        Log.w("BT", "Could not initialize FallbackBluetoothSocket classes.", e);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                        Log.w("BT", e1.getMessage(), e1);
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        Log.w("BT", "Fallback failed. Cancelling.", e1);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!success) {
                throw new IOException("Could not connect to device: "+ device.getAddress());
            }

            return bluetoothSocket;
        }

        private boolean selectSocket() throws IOException {
            if (candidate >= uuidCandidates.size()) {
                return false;
            }

            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
            UUID uuid = uuidCandidates.get(candidate++);

            Log.i("BT", "Attempting to connect to Protocol: "+ uuid);
            if (secure) {
                Method m = null;


                try {
                    m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                 try {
                    tmp = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            } else {
                tmp = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);

            }
            bluetoothSocket = new NativeBluetoothSocket(tmp);

            return true;
        }

        public static interface BluetoothSocketWrapper {

            InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException;

            OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException;

            String getRemoteDeviceName();

            void connect() throws IOException;

            String getRemoteDeviceAddress();

            void close() throws IOException;

            BluetoothSocket getUnderlyingSocket();

        }


        public static class NativeBluetoothSocket implements BluetoothSocketWrapper {

            private BluetoothSocket socket;

            public NativeBluetoothSocket(BluetoothSocket tmp) {
                this.socket = tmp;
            }

            @Override
            public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
                return socket.getInputStream();
            }

            @Override
            public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
                return socket.getOutputStream();
            }

            @Override
            public String getRemoteDeviceName() {
                return socket.getRemoteDevice().getName();
            }

            @Override
            public void connect() throws IOException {
                socket.connect();
            }

            @Override
            public String getRemoteDeviceAddress() {
                return socket.getRemoteDevice().getAddress();
            }

            @Override
            public void close() throws IOException {
                socket.close();
            }

            @Override
            public BluetoothSocket getUnderlyingSocket() {
                return socket;
            }

        }

        public class FallbackBluetoothSocket extends NativeBluetoothSocket {

            private BluetoothSocket fallbackSocket;

            public FallbackBluetoothSocket(BluetoothSocket tmp) throws FallbackException {
                super(tmp);
                try
                {
                  Class<?> clazz = tmp.getRemoteDevice().getClass();
                  Class<?>[] paramTypes = new Class<?>[] {Integer.TYPE};
                  Method m = clazz.getMethod("createRfcommSocket", paramTypes);
                  Object[] params = new Object[] {Integer.valueOf(1)};
                  fallbackSocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(tmp.getRemoteDevice(), params);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw new FallbackException(e);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
                return fallbackSocket.getInputStream();
            }

            @Override
            public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
                return fallbackSocket.getOutputStream();
            }


            @Override
            public void connect() throws IOException {
                fallbackSocket.connect();
            }


            @Override
            public void close() throws IOException {
                fallbackSocket.close();
            }

        }

        public static class FallbackException extends Exception {

            /**
             * 
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public FallbackException(Exception e) {
                super(e);
            }

        }
    }





(MainActivity.java:367)
try {
                        engineRpmCommand.run(mmInStream, mmOutStream);
                        speedCommand.run(mmInStream, mmOutStream);
                        fueltypeCommand.run(mmInStream, mmOutStream);
                        System.out.println("Commands Processed");
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        367-->              e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println("outside try catch");
                }
(ObdCommand.java:164)
protected void readRawData(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        byte b = 0;
        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();

        // read until '>' arrives
164-->      while ((char) (b = (byte) in.read()) != '>')
            res.append((char) b);
```

Comment: In the future when posting, it will be helpful to provide users the specific line that matches up with the line numbers you have provided in your stack trace post.  OdbCommand.readRawData at line 164 and MainActivity line 367 would have been helpful information.

Comment: @ Jay Snayder check now the edited post .

Comment: I have no answer for you since I cannot go through your code line by line, (common is damn too much...), You can use my simple test app from https://github.com/Hesamedin/ELM327

Comment: Please note that above app does not work on all cars. I tested on 5-6 different cars and I got answer on just two of them. It is because my OBD-II device does not support all different protocols.

Comment: @Poonam Kukreti Would you mind sharing this project with me? I'm working on pretty much the exact same thing and it would be really nice to have this to have as a reference for my project.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked if your string builder / buffer contains anything at the time the exception is thrown?

I've had this trouble with Bluetooth on a Nexus 7 2012 and the only thing I can suggest is that you Thread.sleep() while waiting for data and use .available() from the stream to make sure you don't read more than what is available.

You could sleep loop while .available() is zero and not equal to the amount as the last loop, and then assume you have all the data when it stabilizes. Alternatively you can simply catch the exception and assume you have received all the data at that point.

Answer (score 0):

I think its a bug in read() method. From @Keilaron's answer.. I tried this and this works:

```
    while (inputStream.available() == 0);
    val available = inputStream.available()
    val bytes = ByteArray(available)
    inputStream.read(bytes, 0, available)
    val text = String(bytes)
```